# function including jQuery ajax not returning data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 2 functions that fetch data via the jQuery AJAX method.

Both look identical save for the URL. Both requests are successful and show the data in console, but only one returns the data through the parent function.

**saveLoc** fetches data that says *"OK"*, and the *"OK"* is returned if printed to console in the parent code.
**getLoc** fetches data that is a number, say *"17"*. The number is printed to console from within the function, but in the parent code, the variable (**savedLoc**) simply returns *undefined*

Any advice? Am I missing something?

```js
function saveLoc(story,chapter,loc) {
 jQuery.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "index.php?action=saveloc&story="+story+"&chapter="+chapter+"&loc="+loc,
      data: "",
      cache: false,
      success: function (data2) {
        console.log("Location saved: "+loc);
        return data2;
      }
    });
}


function getLoc(story,chapter) {
 jQuery.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "index.php?action=getloc&story="+story+"&chapter="+chapter,
      data: "",
      cache: false,
      success: function (data) {
        console.log("Location retrieved: "+data);
        return data;
      }
    });
}

$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    if (results==null){
       return null;
    }
    else{
       return decodeURI(results[1]) || 0;
    }
}
var story = $.urlParam('story');
var chapter = $.urlParam('chapter');

$(document).ready(function(){
 var start = 1;
 var savedLoc = getLoc(story,chapter);
 
 console.log("savedLoc: "+savedLoc);
 if(savedLoc > 0) {
  var d = $(document).height(),
   c = $(window).height();

  var scrollPos = Math.floor((savedLoc / 100) * (d - c));
  window.scrollTo(0, scrollPos);
 }
 setTimeout(function() {
  $(window).on('scroll', function(){
   console.log("scroll detected");
   setTimeout(function() {
    var s = $(window).scrollTop(),
     d = $(document).height(),
     c = $(window).height();

    var scrollPercent = (s / d) * 100;
    saveLoc(story,chapter,scrollPercent);
   },3000);
  });
 },6000)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The ajax `getLoc` is a asynchronous task, so your `savedLoc = getLoc();` will not get the return value of it's `success` function.

For managin asynchronous tasks, like ajax, there are some solutions:

1. Original and Simple way: If you want to get the return value of ajax, you should use a global variable, and transfer a callback into the ajax function, like `getLoc`, then call the callback in success;
2. Promise, manage the asynchronous tasks with synchronous way, refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise;
3. manage the asynchronous tasks with synchronous way provided in ES6, refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator
4. async await, a replacement for generator, refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

and for more information, refer to  the blog, https://blog.risingstack.com/asynchronous-javascript/

```js
function saveLoc(story,chapter,loc) {
 jQuery.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "index.php?action=saveloc&story="+story+"&chapter="+chapter+"&loc="+loc,
      data: "",
      cache: false,
      success: function (data2) {
        console.log("Location saved: "+loc);
        return data2;
      }
    });
}


function getLoc(story,chapter, callback) {
 jQuery.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "index.php?action=getloc&story="+story+"&chapter="+chapter,
      data: "",
      cache: false,
      success: function (data) {
        console.log("Location retrieved: "+data);
                savedLoc = data;
        callback && callback();
      }
    });
}

$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    if (results==null){
       return null;
    }
    else{
       return decodeURI(results[1]) || 0;
    }
}
var savedLoc;
var story = $.urlParam('story');
var chapter = $.urlParam('chapter');

$(document).ready(function(){
 var start = 1;
 getLoc(story,chapter, afterLocCallback);
 
 function afterLocCallback() {
    console.log("savedLoc: "+savedLoc);
    if(savedLoc > 0) {
      var d = $(document).height(),
        c = $(window).height();

      var scrollPos = Math.floor((savedLoc / 100) * (d - c));
      window.scrollTo(0, scrollPos);
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        console.log("scroll detected");
        setTimeout(function() {
          var s = $(window).scrollTop(),
            d = $(document).height(),
            c = $(window).height();

          var scrollPercent = (s / d) * 100;
          saveLoc(story,chapter,scrollPercent);
        },3000);
      });
    },6000)
  }
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `getLoc` is not returning anything. so put a `return` statement in there.

secondly, $.ajax returns jqXHR object. You can use `then`, `done`, `fail` methods on this object. If you are not familiar with these read about promise concepts.

Once your async call is successful do the rest of the operations inside the `then` method.

```
function saveLoc(story,chapter,loc) {
    //return the ajax promise here
    return jQuery.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "index.php?action=saveloc&story="+story+"&chapter="+chapter+"&loc="+loc,
                        data: "",
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (data2) {
                                console.log("Location saved: "+loc);
                                return data2;
                        }
                });
}


function getLoc(story,chapter) {
    //return the ajax promise here
    return jQuery.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "index.php?action=getloc&story="+story+"&chapter="+chapter,
                        data: "",
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                                console.log("Location retrieved: "+data);
                                return data;
                        }
                });
}

$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    if (results==null){
       return null;
    }
    else{
       return decodeURI(results[1]) || 0;
    }
}
var story = $.urlParam('story');
var chapter = $.urlParam('chapter');

$(document).ready(function(){
    var start = 1;
     getLoc(story,chapter).then(function(data){
        var savedLoc = data;
        console.log("savedLoc: "+savedLoc);
        if(savedLoc > 0) {
            var d = $(document).height(),
                c = $(window).height();

            var scrollPos = Math.floor((savedLoc / 100) * (d - c));
            window.scrollTo(0, scrollPos);
        }
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(window).on('scroll', function(){
                console.log("scroll detected");
                setTimeout(function() {
                    var s = $(window).scrollTop(),
                        d = $(document).height(),
                        c = $(window).height();

                    var scrollPercent = (s / d) * 100;
                    // I think you are not using the return value of this call. So not using any promise then here.
                    saveLoc(story,chapter,scrollPercent);
                },3000);
            });
        },6000)
    });

});
```